# TOP command memory usage

Tags: linux, top, suse

Under SuSE, (Mem:  31908592k total, 31421504k used,) how do i know which process or program using my memory?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The standard (command-line) program for checking cpu/memory usage for processes is `top` there is also a slightly more feature-full `htop` however on a lot of systems its bound to `top` anyway (same way `bash` is almost always bound to `sh` on most modern linux systems). There are also various GUI wrappers for top/htop available

After opening top, clicking `M` will sort by memory usage.

**EDIT - 4-12**
For clarity I decided to expand on the sorting. Here is a typical `top` window when run from the terminal shell, this is already sorted by `%MEM`

[image]

The column that interests you most is `%MEM` which will give you the share of total available memory used by that process. `VIRT` gives the virtual memory footprint of the process, of which only `RES` amount is currently in physical memory (the rest is swapped out, and not currently shown on the table)

In order to sort by a column you hit `F` (shift-F) and the screen will change to the following

[image]

as you can see, hitting `n` will select sort by memory percentage (hit enter to return back to the table view). (There is a legacy shortcut Shift-m that will toggle sort by memory when hit on the table view) You can use `<` and `>` in the table view (shift - , and shift-.) to cycle the column that is sorted.

At the table view, hitting lowercase `m` will toggle the memory summary view. [image]

*Note:* I played around with sorting columns so the columns are shuffled from the first image.

Like a lot of unix/linux command line utilities there are many little tricks and things and hidden features - top is a very powerful tool. For instance, you can show multiple tables at the same time (say the top 5 instead of top 20 but for 4-5 different parameters)- how? I don't know, but I accidentally got to that when taking the screenshots. A full chapter of a good book on *nix can be devoted to `top`, so the summary above is just a small primer to get what *you* need to know about your processes.

Comment: Crasic, thank you for your answer, i know top command will show you:(Mem:  31908592k total, 31153712k used,   754880k free,) but whant i need to know is were all this memory is used.

Comment: Look in the "%MEM" column of top.

Comment: @AlBouazizi Top will by default sort processes (the list below the banner bar) by CPU hitting `M` (i.e. Shift-m) will resort the list by memory usage.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answers, i learn new things.. but still don't know the 31GB of used by which program/process.. Thank you again

Comment: @AlBouazizi what is the program that is at the top of the page when you sort by memory usage?

Comment: I'll add to crasic's response that if you run top, then press `z` key then `x` key top will highlight the sorted column (descending order). Then, you can then use `<` and `>` to change the sorted column (to switch between %cpu and %mem for example). hth

Answer (score 1):

This will ouput pmem & rss longs of processes, worth to try.

```
ps -eo pid,pmem,rss,comm --sort rss
```

Comment: Risyasin, i tried your command but did not help with what i'm looking. i have 31GB of used memory. I need to know who used this memory. Thank you any how.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command:

```
ps ww -eo pid,pcpu,pmem,rss,cmd --sort rss
```

The field "rss" indicates the memory usage

--sort rss - meaning sort by memory usage desc