# Linux memory usage doesn't add up

Tags: memory, ubuntu-12.04, top

I try to monitor the memory usage in my ubuntu server. When I run 'top' command, it shows 70% of the memory is used. (shown in the 'Mem:' line). But I want to find the processes that take my memory usage and add them up, it's far from 70%. Can anyone help explain that for me?

Thanks a lot!

Here is my top command result:

```
top - 20:59:06 up 23 days, 33 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.12, 0.09
Tasks:  92 total,   1 running,  91 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4124236k total,  2903104k used,  1221132k free,   147508k buffers
Swap:  4192252k total,      440k used,  4191812k free,  2596860k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
30558 mysql     20   0  311m  36m 5956 S    0  0.9   0:00.74 mysqld
28848 jiechao   20   0 50688 9244 3144 S    0  0.2   0:05.65 python
  956 root      20   0 11712 8004 2964 S    0  0.2   0:39.26 ddclient - slee
28846 jiechao   20   0 49256 7652 3280 S    0  0.2   0:07.17 python
22284 jiechao   20   0 10400 6876 1664 S    0  0.2   0:00.49 bash
30433 jiechao   20   0 10344 6776 1620 S    0  0.2   0:00.46 bash
31053 jiechao   20   0 10344 6768 1612 S    0  0.2   0:00.47 bash
28847 jiechao   20   0 48168 6096 2980 S    0  0.1   0:00.59 python
29178 www-data  20   0  228m 5392 2052 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
29179 www-data  20   0 12796 5148 1920 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
29180 www-data  20   0 12796 5148 1920 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
29181 www-data  20   0 12796 5148 1920 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
29182 www-data  20   0 12796 5148 1920 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
29183 www-data  20   0 12796 5148 1920 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
  999 root      20   0 11396 3948 2052 S    0  0.1   0:21.21 apache2
  926 whoopsie  20   0 24572 3284 2280 S    0  0.1   0:00.18 whoopsie
30933 root      20   0  9604 3104 2484 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd
22164 root      20   0  9604 3096 2484 S    0  0.1   0:00.01 sshd
30313 root      20   0  9604 3096 2480 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd
24302 root      20   0  9632 3024 2428 S    0  0.1   0:00.07 sshd
  787 root      20   0  6664 2424 1988 S    0  0.1   0:00.05 sshd
    1 root      20   0  3504 1876 1276 S    0  0.0   0:01.57 init
24421 jiechao   20   0  9632 1596  992 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
  812 syslog    20   0 31044 1484 1008 S    0  0.0   1:47.00 rsyslogd
```

Comment: I believe a better answer is here: https://superuser.com/a/270201/265896

Answer (score 4):

Sure that number is a combination of RAM being used by process and buffers and cache for files. Linux has a philosophy of maxing out the use of RAM for files accessed rather than having to hit the hard drive for these files.

Try either using the command `free` or looking at the kernel itself via this command, `cat /proc/meminfo.`

**free**

```
% free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       7987492    7717152     270340          0     314644    2435048
-/+ buffers/cache:    4967460    3020032
Swap:      5963772       1304    5962468
```

**cat /proc/meminfo**

```
% cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        7987492 kB
MemFree:          284328 kB
Buffers:          314384 kB
Cached:          2427852 kB
SwapCached:          116 kB
Active:          4698232 kB
Inactive:        2374796 kB
Active(anon):    3756264 kB
Inactive(anon):   768392 kB
Active(file):     941968 kB
Inactive(file):  1606404 kB
Unevictable:          68 kB
Mlocked:              68 kB
SwapTotal:       5963772 kB
SwapFree:        5962468 kB
Dirty:               452 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4330964 kB
Mapped:           185540 kB
Shmem:            193864 kB
Slab:             306532 kB
SReclaimable:     261520 kB
SUnreclaim:        45012 kB
KernelStack:        6192 kB
PageTables:        94376 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     9957516 kB
Committed_AS:    9671884 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      585392 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359040964 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       12288 kB
DirectMap2M:     8237056 kB
```

The `free` command will show you total RAM, 7987492, in my case, of which 7717152 is being used and 270340 is free. This is a combination of the RAM, buffers and cache. The 2nd line shows you how much of that RAM is being used by the buffers and cache, 4967460, which means I really have 3020032 of RAM free.

From an [itworld.com article](http://www.itworld.com/it-managementstrategy/280695/making-sense-memory-usage-linux?page=0,2) on making sense of memory usage:

> The buffers number represents in-memory blocks that result from the
>   kernel accessing the disk, such as when the kernel needs to read the
>   contents of files. The cached figure tells us how much RAM is being
>   used to cache the content of recently read files. The buffer figure
>   increases when the file system layer is bypassed while the cache grows
>   when the file system is used. Both grow as read operations increase.

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that the Linux kernel's memory manager will free any RAM being used for buffers & cache is an application actually needs it.

**Resources**

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-memory-usage/
- [Making sense of memory usage on Linux](http://www.itworld.com/it-managementstrategy/280695/making-sense-memory-usage-linux)